# DAO RecordsAffected does not return the right value after passthru merge

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, dao

The following code calls a passthru query (PTQ) and should display a message indicating the number of records affected:

```
With CurrentDb
    .Execute "ArticleClientTmpUpdate"
    MsgBox .RecordsAffected & " records updated"
End With
```

The PTQ does a simple merge:

```
merge into dbo.ArticlesClients ac
using (select * from dbo.ArticlesClientsTmp) act on ac.IdArticle = act.IdArticle and ac.IdClient = act.IdClient 
when matched then 
    update  SET ac.IdArticle = act.[idArticle], 
                ac.IdClient = act.[idclient], 
                ac.RefClient = act.[refClient], 
                ac.Commentaire = act.[commentaire], 
                ac.ModDate = getdate()
when not matched then 
    insert (idArticle, idClient, RefCLient, Commentaire)
    values (act.idArticle, act.idClient, act.RefCLient, act.Commentaire);
```

When executed from SSMS after emptying the target table, I can see that 9200 rows are affected (created for instance).
When executing the same merge using VBA above, it says "0 records imported", but does the job and creates the 9200 records.
Any explanation ? Is there a workaround to that issue ? Will it be any better using an ADO `connection` instead of DAO `CurrentDb` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. A Pass-Through query with `ReturnsRecords = False` is sent to the server, and that's it from Access's point of view.

`.RecordsAffected` is never set for Pass-Through queries.

You will have to create a stored procedure that executes your SQL, then returns the number of records.

From https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/204949-passthrough-queries-recordsaffected

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ...

SET NOCOUNT ON;

<your Update query here>

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS myROWCOUNT;
```